# Get key in dictionary with optional tuple parameter

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary that looks like this `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, bool>, string>`

Let's say I have an entry like `(1, 2, true) = "Word"`

I want to be able to index the dictionary by only doing `(1, null, true)` and I want it to return the entry I mentioned before since the first and third values in the tuple are the same (ignoring the second since it's null)

Is there a way to do this? If not what is a suggestion for a new structure that would accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: So what if you _also_ have an entry `(1, 3, true) = "Foo"`?

Comment: " I want it to return the entry..." why only 1 entry? looks like you would like to return all entries that match the first and third creterion... and ignoring the second. like:  ((1, 1, true)), (1, 3, true), (1, 42, true)

Comment: Is equality based on item1 and item3 only?

Comment: If you want only the first int as the index then use a Dictionary that has an int as key, not a Tuple

Comment: A dictionary is optimized for exact key lookups only, so no partial tuple matching and no lookups with types that don't match (`int` is not `int?` and `null`s are not permitted). A simple list of values could be searched using any `.Where` you please; to optimize lookups on particular fields or field combinations you could create helper dictionaries or sets (indexing on `(1, true)` for example). You can, of course, also just plain search the dictionary's key collection, though this is not optimized the way a dictionary lookup is.

Comment: A dictionary can be constructed with a custom `IEqualityComparer`...

Comment: Basically, I have an if statement later on that checks if something is true, then if it is, index it by the first and third value, otherwise index it by the second and third value. So the first or second will be ignored

Comment: How many items are we talking about? If there are a very large number a database would typically be the way to go, if there are not that many a simple linear search might be easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to create a struct to use instead of your Tuple, overriding GethashCode() (implement Equals too, to be consistent) :

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int? FirstNumber { get; set; }

    public int? SecondNumber { get; set; }

    public bool TheBoolean { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals((MyStruct)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyStruct obj)
    {
        return (!obj.FirstNumber.HasValue || !this.FirstNumber.HasValue || 
                  obj.FirstNumber.Value == this.FirstNumber.Value)
            && (!obj.SecondNumber.HasValue || !this.SecondNumber.HasValue || 
                  obj.SecondNumber.Value == this.SecondNumber.Value)
            && obj.TheBoolean == this.TheBoolean;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (!this.FirstNumber.HasValue ? 0 : this.FirstNumber.GetHashCode())
            ^ (!this.SecondNumber.HasValue ? 0 : this.SecondNumber.GetHashCode())
            ^ this.TheBoolean.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public static void Test()
{
    var obj1 = new MyStruct
    {
        FirstNumber = 1,
        SecondNumber = 2,
        TheBoolean = true
    };

    var obj2 = new MyStruct
    {
        FirstNumber = 1,
        SecondNumber = null,
        TheBoolean = true
    };

    var dico = new Dictionary<MyStruct, string>
    {
        { obj1, "Word" }
    };

    var result = dico[obj2];
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is that you really need to have identical match between your `TKey, TValue`pairs. So, according to your structure, you could try something like this:

`Dictionary<tuple<int, bool>, string>`

where, in the dictionary creation step, you take in two ints, and combine them into a new, unitque value to add to your dictionary. Here is an example:

```cs
public static void AddToDictionary(
    this Dictionary<Tuple<int, bool>, string> dictionary,
    Tuple<int, int, bool> oldKey,
    string value)
  {
    var key = new Tuple<int, bool>(oldKey.Item1 + oldKey.Item2, oldKey.Item3);
    dictionary[key] = value;
  }
```

Bear in mind that the key values must be UNIQUE. Otherwise, you will overwrite older entries.

Another structure that you can have is a Dictionary of Dictionaries. Since you are only interested in the first int, and since the second int might be null, you can have this:

`Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Tuple<int?, bool>, string>>`

This way, you can get something like this:

```cs
var keyTuple = new Tuple<int, int?, bool>(1, null, true);

myDictionary[keyTuple .Item1][new Tuple<int?, bool>(keyTuple.Item2, keyTuple.Item3)] 
    = "string value";
```

But, again, it starts to get verbose... a lot.